# xp:text does not render tagName property correctly within a repeat

Tags: xpages

I'm trying to generate a grid layout from a repeat control. Inside the repeat control i'm using a xp:text control to control my compute the output. When I use the tagName property with the predefined tags the tags are generated correctly.

When i'm using other tags such as tr or td the tag is not rendered at all. Is this a bug or a feature ?

```
<xp:repeat id="rptViewCategory"
                            var="PublicationCategory" indexVar="i" disableTheme="true"
                            repeatControls="false" disableOutputTag="false">

                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return getCategories(pubNav);}]]></xp:this.value>


                            <xp:text tagName="tr" id="txtHeader">
                                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var category:NotesViewEntry = PublicationCategory;
    if(category.isCategory()){
        var c:NotesViewColumn =     vwPublications.getColumn(1);
        var nav:NotesViewNavigator = pubNav;
        var firstChild = nav.getChild(category);

        var values:java.util.Vector = firstChild.getColumnValues();


            return values.get(0);


    }
    }]]></xp:this.value>
                            </xp:text>
<datatable></datable>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="4">
                                    <xp:link>
                                        <xp:this.text><![CDATA[#{javascript:return getComponent("txtHeader").value;}]]></xp:this.text>
                                    </xp:link>
                                </td>
                            </tr>



                        </xp:repeat>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tagName options are "**div**", "**span**", "**h1**", "**h2**", and "**h3**". The renderer will ignore anything that is not one of the options on the list (including "**h4**" which would seem to be an over site.) Since "**tr**" is not a valid option it ignores it

So your only choice is to do this with an HTML pass through computed text field.

/Newbs

Answer (score 1):

How about set the text to display as html, disable the output tag, and just add the  inside it

Comment: This aint an valuable option ofcourse. If there is a 'tagname' property I would expect that it would render that tagname unless statet otherwise in the tooltip help. I just found out that it only renders the tagname if the html which is generated by the xpage/custom control would generate correct HTML. Which is, ofcourse, logical but should be a 'warning' on the tagname attribute.